# Logging all function calls in a program

Tags: debugging

I want to write a program (or find a program) that logs all function calls that a program makes. I don't have the program's source code.

Thanks.

Comment: which programming language is it?

Comment: Have you tried `strace` on a unix-ish system?

Comment: If you are looking for answers, you should add information: Operating system, kind of program (exe oder java-class or whatever) etc...

Answer (score 1):

Start from here: http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/fenris/debug-tools.html

Comment: Thanks for the replies.
System is windows xp and this program is an .exe (a game). That link has useful tools but I couldn't find any that can log all function calls.

Comment: Looks like you've got no symbols information any way, so your best bet is to do the autopsy with IDA or a similar tool.

Comment: I already tried IDA and OllyDbg for this. IDA has a tool that logs only calls to/from windows dlls, does not log calls from inside the program. Olly has a tool that logs everything including all calls, but its too heavy and logs a line for every "mov", "push", "pop" and so on. I need something that logs only function calls.

Comment: IDA is scriptable, so you can automate the tracing as you like. Alternatively, you can process your 'heavy' log and extract calls only from it. Any way, without symbols this kind of log is relatively useless, you still have to trace an execution interactively to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I don't know a way to make scripts for IDA. What I wanna do is - run the game for 10 seconds and see for this 10 seconds, witch functions are accessed and how many times and that will solve my problem. About the logs in olly - game is unusable while logging this, and it logs around 800 events per second and  it still can't log everything. You can try it to see what I'm talking about. :)
And no symbols needed, just the addresses are anough for me.